# The leaf's labels aren't showing completely when I use as.dendrogram

Tags: r, label, axis-labels, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

When I plot the dendrogram using "as.dendrogram" all the leaf labels are cut.
See those linked images below as examples:

When I plot using "hclust" (all labels showing correctly)
[Dendrogram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXoES.jpg)

When I plot using "as.dendrogram"
[Dendrogram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k8MS.jpg)

Codes:

The data I created just to show the problem

```r
test <- matrix(c(34,34,32,27,12,1,2,1,1,1), ncol=2)
colnames(test) <- c('Variable1', 'Variable2')
rownames(test) <- c('African Forest Elephant', 'Asian Domestic Elephant','African White Rhino','West African Giraffe','African Mountain Gorilla')
test_table <- as.table(test)
```

To plot the first linked image

```r
hctest = hclust(dist(test_table))
plot(hctest, axes = FALSE)
```

The second one

```r
hctest = as.dendrogram(hctest)
plot(hctest, edge.root = TRUE, horiz = TRUE)
```

PS: If I use "horiz = FALSE" the same problem persists. I tried exporting the image and also tried using R markdown, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this with `par` by adjusting the plot margins `mar=c(bottom, left, top, right)`. (Defaults are `c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1`).

```
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 10) + 0.1)
plot(hctest, edge.root=TRUE, horiz=TRUE)
```

[image]

***Data***

```
hctest <- structure(list(structure(5L, members = 1L, height = 0, label = "African Mountain Gorilla", leaf = TRUE), 
    structure(list(structure(4L, members = 1L, height = 0, label = "West African Giraffe", leaf = TRUE), 
        structure(list(structure(3L, members = 1L, height = 0, label = "African White Rhino", leaf = TRUE), 
            structure(list(structure(1L, label = "African Forest Elephant", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE), 
                structure(2L, label = "Asian Domestic Elephant", members = 1L, height = 0, leaf = TRUE)), members = 2L, midpoint = 0.5, height = 1)), members = 3L, midpoint = 0.75, height = 2.23606797749979)), members = 4L, midpoint = 0.875, height = 7.07106781186548)), members = 5L, midpoint = 0.9375, height = 22.0227155455452, class = "dendrogram")
```